# web api 2 ExceptionHandlerFilter OnExceptionAsync not fired

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, error-handling, async-await

My first question after 6 years of development, so...hello everybody.
I've searched everywhere about this topic, but nothing helped me.

I've moved all my controller's methods form sync to async. Before all worked well, when an exception was thrown, the OnException method was fired.

Now when an exception is thrown inside an async controller method there is no way to fire the OnException or OnExceptionAsync method.

Here is my code

```
  public class ExceptionHandlerFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage();
        resp.Content = new StringContent(context.Exception.Message + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + context.Exception.StackTrace);

        if (context.Exception is NotImplementedException)
            resp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented;
        else if (context.Exception is NotFoundException)
            resp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        else if (context.Exception is ArgumentException)
            resp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        else
            resp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        context.Response = resp;
    }

    public override Task OnExceptionAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var task = base.OnExceptionAsync(context, cancellationToken);
        return task.ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage();
            resp.Content = new StringContent(context.Exception.Message + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + context.Exception.StackTrace);

            if (context.Exception is NotImplementedException)
                resp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented;
            else if (context.Exception is NotFoundException)
                resp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            else if (context.Exception is ArgumentException)
                resp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            else
                resp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

            context.Response = resp;
        });
    }        
}
```

This is my controller

```
[ExceptionHandlerFilter]
public class FascicolazioneController : ApiController
{      

    [ActionName("ClassificaFascicolaArchivisticamente")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async void ClassificaFascicolaArchivisticamente(string progressivoAnnuo, string archivio, int fascicoloId, string classificazione)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        using (var client = new Cad.BDI.Archiflow.FacadeArchiflow("SUPER", this.GetTypeAndMethodName()))
        {


            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => client.ClassificaFascicolaArchivisticamente(
                ProgressivoAnnuo.Parse(progressivoAnnuo), archivio, fascicoloId, Classificazione.Parse(classificazione)));
        }
    }
```

I've tried setting the proper line of code in WebApiConfig and/or global.asax adding the ExceptionHadlerFilter other than set the attribute only on controller, but nothing helped me

Comment: Try moving the call to `base.OnExceptionAsync` after you create your response. Also, don't use `ContinueWith`, use `async-await` if needed. Will shorten your code and make it more readable.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working. The strange thing is that, when there is an exception on sync controller method, the OnExceptionAsync is fired!! But nothing is fired on async controller method on the exception filter class. Cant' understand why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out thanks to this article

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

The problem is the signature of the controller method. Never use

```
    public async void Bla(){}
```

instead i should've used

```
   public async Task Bla(){}
```